# Circular Reference error when serializing objects. One to many associated objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, serialization

I have two simple Lists that auto generated from EF:

```
public partial class Visitor
{
    public Visitor()
    {
        this.Visits = new HashSet<Visit>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PermitId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
}

public partial class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VisitType { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Visitor_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

In WCF method i attempted return the following result:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Visitor))]
[KnownType(typeof(Visit))]
[KnownType(typeof(ICollection<Visit>))]
public class ServiceVisit : IServiceVisit
{

    public List<Visitor> AllVisitors()
    {
        using (var te = new TurnstileDbEntities())
        {
            te.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            return te.Visitors.Include("Visits").ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

But I received an exception:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:AllVisitorsResult. Message InnerException "Object
>   graph for type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[TurnstileWcfService.Visit,
>   TurnstileWcfService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]" contains cycles and cannot be serialized if
>   reference tracking is disabled".

In all similar treads are advised to do so:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

or use third part serialization library  (Newtonsoft.Json). But it is not my option. Because i don't want use Json in WinForms app.
How can i fix this and what other solutions are there?

Comment: try adding `[IgnoreDataMember]` on `Visitor` property inside `Visits`

Comment: or `[NonSerialized()]` as shown in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you. [IgnoreDataMember] is work. But in my case i use auto-generated models. And I see following comment "Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated." and "Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.". Should I wrap auto generated classes in my similar classes?

Comment: if you are dealing with third-party entities, it is ideally preferred not to use them directly but creating objects at your business layer that serves your purpose

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a simple example of how to do it better. All what i've done it is add in my WCF service refference on ADO.NET Entity data model. I have no BL and it is simple example in which i trying to understand how works serialization in wcf. I'm new in wcf.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I have faced this issue several times and can be solved with the following solution:

`[IgnoreDataMember]` literally ignores the member, and the `.Include` suddenly doesn't make sense.

The `[Serializable]` , `[DataContact...]` and `[KnownType(typeo...)]` attributes should be added for each class instead of the Service:

XAML:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Visit))]
public partial class Visit
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int VisitType { get; set; }
  public System.DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
  public Nullable<int> Visitor_Id { get; set; }

  public virtual Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

But since your classes are auto-generated you have to add these modifications to the template file.
[image]

Depends on what you have called your model, there will be a `.tt` file for it. In my case `PolModel.tt`.

In the .tt file find the line with `<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>` and before it add:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

And after it:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(<#=code.Escape(entity)#>))]
```

[image]

And while you are at it, and doing this modifications, you should also consider adding `[DataMember]` attribute to your `properties`, otherwise they will not be available.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Visit))]
public partial class Visit
{
  [DataMember]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int VisitType { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public System.DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Nullable<int> Visitor_Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public virtual Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way EF works when you use Include.  The parent has a reference to the child and the child has a reference to the parent.  WCF will get stuck going between both of these forever.  If you want it to serialize correctly, simply remove all the parent references on the children by setting them to null.  Then the circular reference is gone.  Otherwise, you need to build up your own model and select what you really want from the EF model so you know you aren't returning an infinite loop.  Another reason to not expose EF entities directly. :)